# Make an Element overflow to the Left

Tags: html, css, position, alignment, absolute

I was wondering how to make the rectangle in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gztdG/2/ 'overflow' to the left, so that the rectangle aligns to the right edge of the square. A simple question, but I can't figure out how to achieve this with position: absolute. Thanks in advance. Here is the html:

```
<div id='square'>
<div id='rectangle' />
</div>
```

And here is the css:

```
#square {
height:50px;
width:50px;
background:blue;
margin:auto;
}
#rectangle {
width:200px;
height:20px;
background:red;
position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: This is a [**sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/gztdG/6/). However, be careful when using this because it changes the `direction` and will cause problems when you have text inside the `div`.

Answer (score 2):

I think, the correct answer is to set `position: relative;` on the parent container, then have the rectangle align to the right (see this http://jsfiddle.net/gztdG/5/):

```
#square {
    position: relative; <---
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background:blue;
    margin:auto;
}
#rectangle {
    position:absolute;
    right: 0;           <---
    width:200px;
    height:20px;
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: @Harry you shouldn't remove Your comment. It was really interesting solution.

Comment: Thank you for that response. Although that works with the simpler fiddle, it didn't work with my project- here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q77gN/ The problem is that the rectangle thinks 'right:0' means it should align to the edge of the page. It is essentially the same. Can you see why it is not working?

Comment: Yes, I can. You didn set `position: relative;` on the rectangle's parent. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/Q77gN/2/

Comment: That was exceptionally silly of me. Long story as to why I didn't include that!

Comment: Harry I was interested to see your solution!

Comment: @FinMoorhouse: I have added it back in the comments (under question). Here is the [**link**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/gztdG/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Use negative margin, like that:

```
margin-left:-150px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4qr7z/1/

Comment: The scenario I had in question involved a 100% width, so that value would vary.

Comment: Ok, You did not mention that.

Answer (score 0):

You could also move the div tags so that the rectangle is not wrapped in the square (unless your design requires it)

```
<div id='square'></div>
<div id='rectangle'></div>

#square {
height:50px;
width:50px;
background:blue;
margin-left:150px;
overflow:auto;

}
#rectangle {
width:200px;
height:20px;
background:red;
position:relative;

}
```

This would move the square instead, and use margin-left:150px;

The reason I could imagine this being useful is that pages are loaded from left to right, so if the window is moved, you might experience some displacement, since margin-left:-150px will push it right.